# How do I run a list through a function in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to run my list though a function that I created, but keep getting errors. I don't know what is wrong.

Temperatures in F:

```
temp_f =  [19, 21, 21, 21, 23]
```

Function:

```
def fahrToCelsius(tempFahrenheit):
    return (tempFahrenheit - 32) /1.8
```

The function works, e.g.

```
fahrToCelsius(temp_f[1])
```

gives:

> -6.111111111111111

But running it though a list doesn't. My attempt:

```
temp_c = []

for i in temp_f:
    temp_c.append (fahrToCelsius(temp_f[i]))

print(temp_c)
```

Giving this error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I have tried a few different things, but nothing that I have tried works. Do you have any tips? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need indexing when you're doing direct iteration: `for t in temp_f: temp_c.append (fahrToCelsius(t))`, which is equivalent to `list(map(fahrToCelsius, temp_f))` or `[fahrToCelsius(t) for t in temp_f]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most pythonic solution is to use list comprehension:

```
temp_c = [fahrToCelsius(t) for t in temp_f]
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in temp_f` is actually assigning i to each element in your array, so 19, 21, etc. Therefore, `temp_f[i]` is actually `temp_f[19]`, which is why you are getting the error. Change the loop to:

```
for i in range(0, len(temp_f)):
    temp_c.append (fahrToCelsius(temp_f[i]))
```

or instead:

```
for temp in temp_f:
    temp_c.append (fahrToCelsius(temp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating the list using `for i in temp_f` makes `i` in this context refer to every item in your list.

What you want to do is iterate the list **indices** instead, like `for i in range(len(temp_f))`.

Alternatively, you can iterate the list items like you did, but pass `i` as the parameter to `fahrToCelsius` (instead of `temp_f[i]`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use list as an input for this question as you are trying then use a numpy array instead of list , it will broadcast your conversion

```
import numpy as np
Lis= np.array([30,40,50])
def fahrToCelsius(tempFahrenheit):
    return (tempFahrenheit - 32) /1.8
print(fahrToCelsius(Lis))
```